# difficulty with NA in ifelse

Tags: r

I've read previous posts on this but still dont understand what is happening with my code and why. In other scenarios is seems comparison of NA with other values can cause an issue but I am not doing that here (I dont think).
So,

I have this Data frame

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(x=sample(c(1,0,NA),20,replace=TRUE),
               y=sample(c(1,0,NA),20,replace=TRUE))
```

which give me data that looks like this:

```
    x  y
1  NA NA
2   1  0
3   0  0
4  NA NA
5  NA NA
6   1 NA
```

I want a third variable to be 1 if either x or y is 1, zero if either x or y is zero but not 1, and NA otherwise.

I've tried nesting an `ifelse` like so:

```
df_new<-df %>% mutate(var=ifelse(x==1|y==1,1,
                ifelse(x==0|y==0,0,NA)))
```

which give me:

```
16 NA NA  NA
17  1  1   1
18  0 NA  NA
19 NA  1   1
20  0  1   1
```

but as you can see in line 18 where the new variable should be 0, it is NA. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix the code I've written?

Comment: Check out the duplicate, and try `mutate(var = case_when(x == 1 | y == 1 ~ 1, x == 0 | y == 0 ~ 0, TRUE ~ NA_real_))`.

Comment: When that code is evaluating rows where x is NA it tests `NA==1` (run this code to see). Replace `==` with `%in%` - `mutate(var=ifelse(x%in%1|y%in%1,1, ifelse(x%in%0|y%in%0,0,NA)))`

Comment: You could also try a slightly simpler non-nested `ifelse` statement: `df$new <- ifelse(is.na(df$x) & is.na(df$y), NA, pmax(df$x, df$y, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: pmax can handle the entire operation `df$new2<-pmax(df$x, df$y, na.rm=T)`

Comment: @M.Viking that worked! thanks. I suppose I didn't realize the comparison to NA was happening as you suggest.